# Finding second Highest from repeating values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to find the second highest salaried person from the table which has multiple employees with same salary.

```
 create tablesals (emp_name varchar(10), emp_id INTEGER, salary INTEGER);

insert into sals values ('rr',12,100000);
insert into sals values ('ed',13,100000);
insert into sals values ('ty',14,100000);
insert into sals values ('we',15,80000);
insert into sals values ('wse',16,80000);
insert into sals values ('wa',17,74000);


sel  emp_name,emp_id,salary, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by salary desc) as rrnk from (sel emp_name,emp_id,salary, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by salary order by salary desc) as rnk
from edwdev.sals) x where x.rnk = 2 and rrnk = 2;
```

Above is the query I came up with but im not able to get the correct data.
What changes do I have to make in my query.

Comment: use `dense_rank` instead of `row_number` so all ties will get the same rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `dense_rank()` does what you want?

```
SELECT emp_name,
       emp_id,
       salary
       FROM (SELECT emp_name,
                    emp_id,
                    salary,
                    dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) dr
                    FROM sals) x
       WHERE dr = 2;
```